# Show Taskbar with FMX borderless form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My application main form have `borderStyle = none` and `WindowState = wsMaximized`.
My problem is that the application is covering the windows taskbar. How do i display the windows taskbar?

[image: My Application]

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a solution

Put `Self.Height := Screen.WorkAreaRect.Height;` on `Form OnShow` event